# The weight of $X$ is $\aleph_0$ iff $X$ is second countable

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

Let $\omega(X)=\min\{|\mathcal{B}|:\mathcal{B} \mbox{ is a base of the topology of } X\}$. I want to make sure whether the following statement is true : $\omega(X)=\aleph_0 $ iff $X$ is second countable.

By the definition of the weight of space $X$, if $\omega(X)=\aleph_0 $ then $X$ is second countable. I am not sure whether the converse is also correct. If not, please give me a counterexample.

Comment: Your definition of the weight isn’t quite right: the weight of $X$ is defined to be $$\max\big\{\aleph_0,\min\{|\mathscr{B}|:\mathscr{B}\text{ is a base for }X\big\}\;.$$ With this definition it is true that $X$ is second countable iff its weight is $\aleph_0$; with your definition a second countable space could have finite weight.